# Async file download in VB not working

Tags: c#, webclient

I have the following:

```
wc.DownloadDataCompleted += Wc_DownloadDataCompleted;
FileStream f = File.OpenWrite(insLoc + "\\update.zip");
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/file.zip"), installLoc + "\\file.zip");
```

(and in a separate function)

```
private void Wc_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null) {
            MessageBox.Show("Download success");
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Download failed"); }

        f.Flush();
        f.Dispose();
    }
```

When I check the file it is supposed to be downloading to, it exists, but there is nothing in it (ie, it is 0 bytes). I have flushed the FileStream after the download has finished, so what is happening? I have a progress bar as well, and it slowly increases to 100% so I know it's downloading the ZIP file, and the "Download Success" messagebox is shown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the callback function to save the resulting file (represented as a byte array passed as second argument):

```
wc.DownloadDataCompleted += Wc_DownloadDataCompleted;
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/file.zip"));
```

and then:

```
private void Wc_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null) 
    {
        string resultFile = Path.Combine(insLoc, "update.zip");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(resultFile, e.Result);
        MessageBox.Show("Download success");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download failed"); 
    }
}
```

Now you can quickly see that using this method the entire file is loaded in memory as a byte array before flushing it to the file system. This is hugely inefficient especially if you are downloading large files. For this reason it is recommended to use the [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=VS.110).aspx) method instead.

```
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
string resultFile = Path.Combine(insLoc, "update.zip");
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/file.zip");
wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, resultFile);
```

and the corresponding callback:

```
private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download success");
    }
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Download failed"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method of *WebClient* which I find very simple to use..

```
await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/file.zip"), installLoc + "\\file.zip");
```

That is all. If you want to see the download progress, you can attach to `DownloadProgressChanged` event.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  1) Maybe I am missing something but I don't see in that doc anything saying it isn't raised. 2) If you wrote few lines of codes before commenting you would see that it actually works. In case you want to test **`Webclient wc = new Webclient();
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
    };

    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), filename);`**

Comment: There is a table mapping there which mentions in which method the event gets raised. Pethaps its outdated.